# Can I compare MySQL enums?

Tags: sql, mysql, enums, compare

I have an enumeration: `ENUM( 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'omega' )`

If I sort my table by this column I get them in the correct order defined above.

However, I can't find a way to select a subset of these, e.g. everything before delta. Using `WHERE status < 'delta'` only returns alpha and beta, not gamma. It seems MySQL uses a string comparison, not enum index comparison.

I could use the index numbers - i.e. `WHERE status < 4` - but it's a bit of a code smell (magic numbers) and may break if I insert new values into the enumeration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use data-manipulation methods on metadata, and this is bound to be awkward.

This is a good reason to replace the `ENUM` with a foreign key to a lookup table.  Then you can use conventional data-manipulation techniques.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `status+0` to return the index of the ENUM, starting from 1.

Refer http://serghei.net/docs/database/mysql/doc/E/N/ENUM.html

Answer (score 4):

just came across the same issue. if you want to sort a enum field you have to cast it to a string type first (category is my enum field in the example):

```
SELECT
CONVERT(category USING utf8) as str_category 
FROM
example
GROUP BY
str_category
ORDER BY 
str_category
```

eazy!

Comment: This sounds like the opposite of my question. I wanted the ordering to be numeric, which it does fine. My problem was with the WHERE clause. Though perhaps there's a way to convert the ENUM field to a numerical value and use that? Doesn't really matter to me now, I asked this nearly a year ago and I don't even remember what it was for...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FIELD(column, "string1", "string2", ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) to find rows with any particular subset of possible `ENUM` values.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIELD(`enum_column`, "alpha", "delta", "et cetera");
```

If you want to use the range version, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET("needle", "hay,stack")`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to return the index but you'll have to extract the ENUM list out of the table definition first with another query.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
CREATE fEnumIndex(_table VARCHAR(50), _col VARCHAR(50), _val VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE _lst VARCHAR(8192);
    DECLARE _ndx INT;

    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE,''', ''',','),'enum(',''),')','')
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND
    TABLE_NAME=_table AND COLUMN_NAME=_col INTO _lst;
    SET _ndx = FIND_IN_SET(_val, _lst);
    RETURN _ndx;
END
```

Then use it in a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Status < fEnumIndex('MyTable','Status','delta') ;
```

The `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE,''', ''',','),'enum(',''),')','')` will take the `COLUMN_TYPE` such as `ENUM( 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'omega' )` and turn it into a comma-separated list: `'alpha, beta, gamma, delta, omega'`. Then the `FIND_IN_SET(_val, _lst)` gets the index.

The only thing you need to be careful with is how you define the ENUMs (with or without spaces between the items) and the inner-most `REPLACE` (with or without a space in the from_string).